# Google keeps deleting .NET libraries for Archi Steam Farm

Tags: ubuntu, google-compute-engine

I set up a VM on Google Compute Engine running intel based x86 CPU and Ubuntu 20.04. First thing I did was install .NET core. After that, I downloaded Archi Steam Farm from github, extracted the zip file.

I gave the executable permissions to execute and I tried to run the file.

After running the executable, I got: Could not load file or assembly "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" error.

A DLL named the same way was in the directory when I unzipped ASF, but after running the executable, all the DLLs were gone and the executable was 0kb in size, suggesting it got removed by Google for some reason. I tired redoing this numerous times, but always got the same outcome. After running the executable, the DLLs were gone and the executable was an empty file.

So if this is indeed some antivirus or whatever deleting my files, how can I disable that? It is a fresh Ubuntu install and I can't find any solution on the internet.

If someone could try on their VM and confirm or deny the same behavior, I would be really glad.

Thanks to all for help and ideas. I am happy to provide more information if needed.

Here you can see I extracted, gave permissions and executed all in one go within few seconds. The file it can't find were there before I ran the executable. They disappeared after the execution.

This does not happen with other apps and I tried this on a local Ubuntu machine and I didnt have issues. This only happens on Google Cloud.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n99Gy.png

Comment: Google does not delete your files. You need to look elsewhere. Most likely you are deleting them yourself.

Comment: I think there is an explanation [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46053185/11866104) for your error message.